# Can you run a Java program in Linux using the name only, without the "java" command?

Tags: java, linux, terminal, command-line-interface

If I am writing HelloWorld, is there a way I can run the program from any directory by just typing HelloWorld?  Sort of the same way once you set up Ant, you can just run Ant from any directory?

Just for some details, we are creating a CLI based toolkit for a customer, and just curious if we can compile it, install it, and just have them run it using the toolkit name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can always create a shell script, call it `HelloWorld` and make it run `java` with your JAR.

You'll then need to [`chmod`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod) the script to make it executable, and place it somewhere in your `$PATH`.

The script would like something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/helloworld
java -jar HelloWorld.jar "$@"
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar /path/to/helloworld/HelloWorld.jar "$@"
```

depending on your exact requirements.

Comment: Note that this answer applies to Linux and other Posix OSes only. Windows would require you to create a batch file.

Comment: It's probably better to make the shell script check for the directory where it's located in and use that as the path to the jar file. That way the shell script and the .jar file can be copied to any directory.

Comment: @RudolphEst: True, but the question is specifically about Linux.

Comment: This script runs Java application in a directory which probably differs from what user expects it to be run in, so relative paths passed to the Java application as arguments may change their meanings.

Comment: @NPE I just thought it worth mentioning to people who find the question using a search engine, who might not notice the Linux tag (since it is not specified in the question itself).

Answer (score 2):

Common solution for your problem is to create a separate launcher application, which is non-java application that runs your Java program.  Launcher can be written in some compilable language such as C/C++ and compiled into native executable.  Also it can be written in some interpreted language such as Unix shell, perl, python etc and made executable by adding `#!/path/to/interpreter` line at the beginning of launcher file and setting executable flag on it.  Also there are several utilities that can generate launcher for your program such as [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) or [jsmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

On Linux (specifically), you could use the `/proc` filesystem (see [proc(5)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html) man page) and its [binfmt_misc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc) (actually the `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register` pseudo-file and other pseudofiles under `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/`) to register `java` as the handler for `.class` or `.jar` files. Read the [Documentation/binfmt_misc.txt](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/binfmt_misc.txt) file in the kernel source for gory details.

Then any executable `.jar` file would be interpreted by `java` (or `jexec`)

I'm not sure it is worth the effort. I find that wrapping your Java program in some shell script is much more easy (and more portable, because few Linux systems actually use `binfmt_misc`, and your customer may need some sysadmin skills to enable it).